# How to create a Github login session in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, github, httpurlconnection

I've looked closely at how a browser logs into Github and I wrote Java code that worked in the past.  But Github has changed the form information and now I always get a 422, unprocessable entity.

The form looks like this now:

[image]

The browser posts this request:

[image]

The code I have is in postForm here:

https://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core/src/org/eclipse/oomph/setup/internal/core/util/ECFURIHandlerImpl.java#n3191

The code first visits https://github.com/login to read the form and to gather the session cookies before calling postForm.  Note again that this code used to work with the old form.

The code posts to this URL:

```
https://github.com/session
```

These cookies (from the login page) are passed during the request:

```
_device_id=88017374888aa5aade6c6a463d9c4438
_octo=GH1.1.742511510.1628575212
logged_in=no
_gh_sess=IkXG6whqhY4mDHYWLg%2F8YGLwnlDcXSVHa42dNlWmaiqpbuuY6Eqpj6gsrML6VAyTLaCOW5EXDSOzJbXgRxnc0u81RUU2Noi1EaGDLPcQg4zcHBThpJegnjKl7t4ywbtxv6c2%2BP8NYMYwKzQVFIbpAnSrzXQFmFG4bE0A5Crf849q%2BexLgrJZczReJlREdK3QyUIrX1RTDm3xQMx3wI%2B6URRPGxhJ%2FUW%2FyFCVY47Zob5HzljoGknVTvYAU3v5Zj1OPBNXkBxOexCccuODgENAfw%3D%3D--qOXhOtn%2B4Y60HjsS--%2FCWdOCEjyFFQjVIrzw0rcQ%3D%3D
```

This is the data posted:

authenticity_token=jbaps3xiJIJEHdd75lzGCkhISAYORL9H4jIJxo9Bkcg4fcijAMqqd%2FTSJfhP96vHfYAAhwrf2Gk1YpLgLAGFDQ%3D%3D&login=merks&password=.....trusted_device=&webauthn-support=unknown&webauthn-iuvpaa-support=unknown&return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Flogin&allow_signup=&client_id=&integration=&required_field_cb8e=&timestamp=1628575212099&timestamp_secret=eca4f299e228931d7ce1e5600bf13bf2c8415406811b8f9fbf62b145d408bcec&commit=Sign+in

The data looks pretty much exactly like what the browser sends but always a 422 and I am at my wits end to figure out what I must modify the get a 302, and of course the session cookie so that I can access files in private repositories, like before....

Does anyone have any hints on how I must tweak this to make it work again?  I'm pretty sure the form data being posted is well formed...

Comment: What about using OAuth2? Logging in to GitHub like done in the browser sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It's certainly possible to start from scratch, come up with a different implementation that probably requires libraries that I currently do not require, and then tell people using the existing mechanism that's been working well for years that they need to use a different mechanism because I can't figure out why this no longer works.

Comment: Why do you need your mechanism in the first place? Logging in this way may be against GitHub's Terms of Service. Aside from that, I am unsure about your method working with 2FA.

Comment: Oomph accesses setup resources via plain/raw text URLs .  E.g., https://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/org.eclipse.setup and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/master/groovy-eclipse.setup contain "setups".   These could be in private repositories and these mechanisms were implemented and documented:

Comment: I expect this doesn't with with 2FA; you are probably right that OAuth2 would be better long term.  But no one pays me to solve this problem yet again.  Open source is free for everyone who uses it but not for the one providing it... 

Even answering questions for others isn't free: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=usrinfo&id=2253&

Comment: What do you want to say with this link to your eclipse profile? By the way, GitHub may change their login in the future at any time.

Comment: Oh yes, you need to log in to see that.  The point is that I've answered almost 32,000 questions over the last 20 years on the Eclipse forums.  I don't typically ask any questions anywhere, but I thought I'd give it a try here because the answers here (to other people's questions) have proven very helpful in the past.

I see my documentation link was missing too:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring#Accessing_Setups_that_Require_Authentication

It really did work in the past, I can assure you.  And the implementation is not hard coded to a particular host...

Comment: I have an eclipse account and I was able to view your progile but what does this have to do with your question?

Comment: I can't help with the actual question but: Even though as a user it would of course be be nice to have the installer load a setup from a private location, in your case I would probably avoid having to maintain a login mechanism for platforms like github (or gitlab, bitbucket, etc) if possible. They may change their login process at will (e.g. by switching technologies, changing permissions or even changing their TOS).

Comment: Currently we download the setup manually which works fine because it rarely changes. I think at my last job we had a CI job which published the latest setup which was then accessible through basic auth as a workaround. But I wonder whether it would be possible to load the setup file through git instead, so that git handles credentials?

Comment: I've gone back to using basic authentication with a PAT:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/merks/stuff/master/setups/stuff.setup?oomph_basic_auth=true